# Can anyone give me more info on this sketchy url I recently visited, is it an attack site?

Tags: malware, virus

My girlfriend was browsing images on google when suddenly her browser redirected to this url:

**defender-iies.co.cc/scan3/167**

The site seemed to be posing as an anti virus, saying your computer is at risk and what not. She immediately closed and reset firefox. I then copied the url from her history into google to check it out and see if i could figure out if her computer might be at risk. I couldn't find anything on the url when searching it in google so, trusting my security software (MSE) I visited the url in firefox. What happened next was quite peculiar. Firefox immediatly minimized into a tiny square in the corner of the screen, the exit button was not available so I quickly stopped firefox with task manager. When attempting to reopen Firefox it opened in the same minimized, unusable way about 3 more time until it went back to normal.

After visiting the url I ran virus scans on both machines and they came back saying no threats where detected. Can anyone shed some light on what might have happened and if there are any precautionary measure I should take? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So long as you did not download and run the freesystemscan.exe it tries to give you, you should be fine.

I image it would have been more interesting if you were using IE but FF is usually safe enough.  I visited the site in the latest version of chrome and not much interesting happened besides the download.

EDIT:
Looking at the source code.. it looks like it would try to do something interesting if you visited in IE6.
Then there is a bunch of obfuscated JavaScript I don't feel like peeking around in.